# RegServer on CATIA start (without privileges)

Tags: vb.net, com, catia, tlbimp

We have CATIA R18-R24 available on a network drive, where every designer can start it. 
The problem is, that the VB.Net COM interface does not know the Type Libraries of the started version. To run the RegServer (to register the tlb for the correct version) privileged rights are needed.

Is there any way to register the tlb on startup of CATIA? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.
I have created a encrypted call to the CATIA Regserver with [RunsAsSPC](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspc.html) . It is stored alongside with an privileged account. The encryption ensures, that no user can see the credentials and change to command.
This RunAsSPC call is started within the CATIA start-batch file.